# Android. Добавить контакт во временную адресную книгу

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Есть следующая задача: когда приходит звонок, он отображается в "Журнале 
вызовов" бывает ситуация, когда пользователю нужно временно сохранить контакт, с автоматическим удалением.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача: перехватить этот номер из приложение "Контакты" и записать в свою БД

Вопрос: можно ли в стандартное приложение "Контакты" в этот список(который на картинке) добавить ссылку на свое приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полностью миную операцию копирования номера? Вряд ли ибо это отдельная апк просто вшита как стандартное приложение. Другое дело попытаться отловить интент входящего вызова и выполнять код сохраняющий номер. По ссылке перейди, там будет пункт "Мониторинг звонков"

https://habrahabr.ru/post/162181/